# Mutltiple multiple class instances within a single python object

Tags: python, matlab

I'm in an academic setting and have been working on translating some of my data analysis code base from MATLAB to Python 3.x(Anaconda) using numpy and scipy in order to work with some collaborators who don't have access a MATLAB License. I'm also using it as an excuse to improve my python abilities rather than just copying it all over to Octave and fixing any small issues that crop up. I've got some basic experience with python under my belt at this point but I'm running into problems replicating the behavior of some of the data handling classes in my MATLAB code base with Python classes. The the class in question here basically holds chunks of spectral data along with an identifier and some basic analysis.

Essentially in MATLAB, I end up with an Nx1 instance of the class in question. This lets me look at things on a signal by signal basis by indexing the parent object, which I use to pass all the related data for a signal to later analysis functions.

e.g:

```
% Sample Data
positions = [195, 250, 280];
widths = [5, 5, 10];

Data = DataObject(positions, widths)

>> Data(1)
ans = 
    DataObject with properties:
        value_a: 195
        value_b: 5
```

It also lets me easily get the values across all signals which makes it easy to put into a spreadsheet or report. e.g.

```
>> [Data.value_a]'
ans = [195, 250, 280]
```

(Note: I know in this example it is just returning the input but there are also derived values that I'm concerned with in the real code.)

I've been trying to figure out how to replicate this behavior in python, so ideally I could do something like this:

```
positions = np.array([195, 250, 280])
widths = np.array([5, 5, 10])

Data = DataObject(positions, widths)
>>> Data[1]
<A DataObject containing only the data for the first signal>

>>> Data.value_a
array([195, 250, 280])
```

I tried something similar to what I do in MATLAB by using

```
for idx in range(len(centers)):
            self[idx].center = centers[idx]
```

in the __init__ method, but it just gives me:

```
TypeError: 'SignalPeak' object is not subscriptable
```

Most of google results I've been able to find on how to have multiple instances of an object revolve around putting them in a list and then just iterating through them manually when you want to look at a property from all of them. But I'm wondering if there is a way to do this that acts more akin to what my original code does, or at least wrap that behavior into the class definition.

The MATLAB class definition is:

```
classdef DataObject
    properties
        value_a
        value_b
    end
    methods
        function obj = DataObject(reference, data)
            % reference: a Nx1 vector 
            % data: a Nx1 vector

            obj(size(reference,1),size(reference,2)) = obj; % Creates a Nx1 SignalPeak object

            % Sets the various values
            for idx = 1:length(centers(:))
                obj(idx).value_a = reference(idx)
                obj(idx).value_b = data(idx)
            end
        end    
    end
end
```

Comment: Some sample data would be useful, e.g. where N=3.

Comment: I think you could achieve this with an object that holds a list of your `Data` object, and then iterates through that list. I will try and write something to demonstrate.

Comment: For numeric data, you want to use numpy or pandas, not lists... Btw, have you considered using Octave? https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/

Comment: @Alexander I am using numpy and scipy in the project. I edited the question to include this information as well as some some sample data and a better description of the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do, but I think there is no way around creating a wrapper object that will wrap a list of all of the data objects that you would like. Here's one such implementation:

```
In [18]: class DataObject:
    ...:     def __init__(self, a, b):
    ...:         self.a = a
    ...:         self.b = b
    ...:     def __str__(self):
    ...:         return "DataObject: a={a}, b={b}".format(a=self.a, b=self.b)

In [19]: o1 = DataObject(1, 2)

In [20]: print(o1)
Out[20]: DataObject: a=1, b=2

In [21]: o2 = DataObject(3, 4)

In [22]: print(o2)
Out[22]: DataObject: a=3, b=4

In [23]: objects = DataObjects()

In [24]: objects.add(o1)

In [25]: objects.data_objects
Out[25]: [<__main__.DataObject at 0x103a0f610>]

In [26]: objects.add(o2)

In [27]: objects.data_objects
Out[27]: [<__main__.DataObject at 0x103a0f610>, <__main__.DataObject at 0x103842bd0>]

In [28]: objects.data_objects[1]
Out[28]: <__main__.DataObject at 0x103842bd0>

In [29]: objects.data_objects[1].a
Out[29]: 3

In [30]: objects.a
Out[30]: [1, 3]
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't quite accomplish what I'm after. I've updated the the question with a better description of the desired output!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use pandas for this.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: data = pd.DataFrame({'positions':[195, 250, 280], 'widths':[5,5,10]})

In [3]: data
Out[3]:
   positions  widths
0        195       5
1        250       5
2        280      10
```

Getting values across all signals is as simple as:

```
In [4]: data.positions
Out[4]:
0    195
1    250
2    280
Name: positions, dtype: int64
```

You get the data for a single signal using [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
In [5]: data.iloc[1]
Out[5]:
positions    250
widths         5
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Calculating simple derived columns is easy, and pandas has lots of functions to produce summaries of the data.

```
In [7]: data['areas'] = data.positions * data.widths

In [8]: data
Out[8]:
   positions  widths  areas
0        195       5    975
1        250       5   1250
2        280      10   2800
```

All that would be left is updating your analysis functions to work with dataframes and series.